# direct sum of sub spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I have a doubt 
if T is a linear operator on a vector space x then we know that x(infinite dimensional space) is isomorphic to direct sum of ker(T) and quotient space x/ker(T).now x/ker(T) is isomorphic to range T so it will lead us to conclusion that x is isomorphic to direct sum of ker(T) and range (T).so i want to know what is wrong in above proof.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. The key point is that $X$ is *isomorphic* to that direct sum, not *equal* to it. (It cannot be always equal to the direct sum because the kernel and the range may not be independent; they may even coincide.)

Comment: @lhf but above proof  also leads to a conclusion that sum of ker T and range T is direct sum which is  something absurd.

Comment: Use a cartesian product instead of direct sum if it makes it clearer.

Comment: but proceedings in above proof  leading us to direct sum actually i am new on this topic so i am not getting your point @lhf

Comment: I suggest you add a proof that $X$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $ker(T)$ and $X/ker(T)$.

Comment: we know that there exist a subspace z of x such that x is direct sum of kerT and z .by this we can prove that x/ker T is isomorphic to z hence x is isomorphic to direct sum of x/kerT and kerT @lhf

Comment: Exactly. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: but this statement seems  absurd that x is isomorphic to direct sum of kerT and rangeT because in this case kerT is equal to ker $T^2$ which is not true always @lhf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here direct sum of ker T and range T means cartsian product of ker T and rnge T